# Topological information from metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, geometric-topology

Suppose I am working with a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and I have a particular coordinate expression for the metric $g$.

> What topological information can I infer about the manifold $M$?

---

For example ($S^3$ with [Hopf coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere#Hopf_coordinates)), suppose I have coordinates $(\eta, \xi_1 , \xi_2 ) $ in which the metric takes the form:

$ds^2 = d \eta^2 + \sin^2(\eta) d \xi_1^2 + \cos^2(\eta) d\xi_2^2$

for $0 < \eta < \pi/2$, and $0 < \xi_1 , \xi_2 < 2 \pi$. If I didn't already know this was a metric for $S^3$, how could I work that out? How do I know this isn't a metric for another three manifold, say $S^2 \times S^1$? Are there topological invariants I can compute from the metric to distinguish between, say, these two possibilities?

EDIT: Changed the inequalities to be strict so that the metric in my example doesn't degenerate.

Comment: Are you asking about the metric itself, or its coordinate expression? If you are asking about the coordinate expression, then you have an atlas to figure things out with.

Answer (score 2):

The expression you wrote does not define a Riemannian metric for coordinates on $S^3$, because when $\eta=0$ or $\pi/2$ the metric degenerates. It does define coordinates for a portion of $S^3$, namely the portion where the coordinates satisfy the strict inequalities $0 < \eta < \pi/2$, $0 < \xi_1, \xi_2 < 2 \pi$.

So perhaps you meant to use strict inequalities $0 < \eta < \pi/2$, $0 < \xi_1, \xi_2 < 2 \pi$? In which case I would say that the expression you wrote also defines coordinates for another 3-manifold, namely
$$(0,\pi/2) \times (0,2\pi) \times (0,2\pi)
$$

Comment: You're right, of course. I've edited the inequalities. Is it correct to say that because coordinates describe how some open set of $M$ is homeomorphic to Euclidean space, then a coordinate expression for the metric (in some patch) doesn't intrinsically contain topological information? If that's the case, where does the topology come in? In the transition functions?

More in line with my original question, does a given coordinate expression for the metric place constraints on the possible topologies?

Comment: Nothing in any single coordinate patch can determine global topology: for any Riemannian $m$-manifold $M$, any open subset $U \subset M$ with a diffeomorphism $\phi$ from $U$ to the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and any differentiable $m$-manifold $N$, if we let $V \subset U$ be the inverse image under $\phi$ of the open ball of radius $1/2$, then there exists a Riemannian metric on $N$ having an open subset isometric to $V$. This is an easy exercise in partitions of unity. @MarkB

Comment: On the other hand **global** properties of Riemannian metrics can have strong topological consequences. Just as an example, if $M$ has a complete Riemannian metric whose sectional curvatures are nonpositive at each tangent 2-plane of each point, then the universal cover of $M$ is contractible; that's the Cartan-Hadamard theorem.